# React Native authentication and cloud Firestore for web apps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to both Firebase and React so bear with me here.
I am trying to use cloud Firestore and Authentication in my application but am a little unsure on how to set up my firebase.js file. I have scaled the internet and watched plenty of videos/tutorials but can't seem to figure out how to implement these into my app. It also seems that some tutorials that I watched from 2020 are not out of date.

Here's my code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

// const auth = getAuth();
// signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
//   .then((userCredential) => {
//     // Signed in
//     const user = userCredential.user;
//     // ...
//   })
//   .catch((error) => {
//     const errorCode = error.code;
//     const errorMessage = error.message;
//     // ...
//   });


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app)
// export const auth = app.auth()
export { db }
```

Comment: We can only see that you are initializing Firebase. Can you share any component where you are trying to use it but are facing issues?

Comment: Thanks for your help again, Dharmaraj! I guess I am having difficulty trying to initialize firebase for authentication and the cloud firestore. I am unsure how to set this up

Comment: There must be some error or warnings in console. Can you share screenshot of those?

Comment: I have the cloud firestore working and now I want to add authentication for users to login/logout but am unsure how to set up the initialization for authentication?

Comment: I haven't gotten there to test the auth yet

Comment: I've posted an answer with a simple example on how you can initialize FIrebase auth. If my answer was useful, you can accept and upvote it. [what should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you again for your help, Dharmaraj! By the way, what resources do you like the best for learning/implementing firebase?

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) might be best for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the auth instance from `firebase.js` and then use it in any component you need. Assuming you have a login component:

**firebase.js:**

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)

export { db, auth }
```

**login.jsx:**

```jsx
// login component

import { auth } from "./firebase.js"
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

// run on button click or relevant events
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((user) => {
  console.log(user)
})
```